# Every regular space curve with polynomial coordinates of degree less or equal to 2 is a plane curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having difficulty on the following problem of differential geometry:

$a)$ Verify that the curve $\alpha\colon (0,\infty)\to\mathbb R^3$ given by $\alpha(t)=\left(t,\dfrac{1+t}{t},\dfrac{1-t^2}{t}\right)$ is a plane curve.

$b)$ Verify that every regular curve of $\mathbb R^3$, whose coordinate functions are polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$, is a plane curve.

So, for the first item I tried the following:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x &=& t \\
y &=& \dfrac{1+t}{t} \\
z &=& \dfrac{1-t^2}{t}
\end{array}
\right.
&
\Rightarrow 
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
y = & \dfrac{1+x}{x} & & \\
z = & \dfrac{1-x^2}{x} & = &  \dfrac{(1-x)(1+x)}{x}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
$$

Hence,
$$
z=(1-x)y=y-xy=y-(1+x)=y-1-x
$$

Thus, $\alpha$ lies in the plane $-x+y-z=1$.

For the second item I took the curve

$$
\beta(t)=(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2,b_0+b_1t+b_2t^2,c_0+c_1t+c_2t^2), a_i,b_i,c_i\in\mathbb R.
$$

And wlog I assumed $\beta$ parameterized by the arc length. I tried something over the relation $|\beta'(t)|=1$, but I did not get anything because of the lack of control of the coefficients $a_i,b_i,c_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $E(s,t)=(a_0+a_1t+a_2s,b_0+b_1t+b_2s,c_0+c_1t+c_2s)$ parametrises a plane. You have $\beta(t)=E(t^2,t)$ so $\beta$ is a plane curve.

Answer (score 2):

Every space curve with zero torsion is a plane curve.  If the (time) derivative of the acceleration is zero, then so is torsion.